# who can do an overhaul of landing gear?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, aircraft-maintenance, landing-gear

A manufacturer requires the landing gear of an aircraft to be overhauled at a 10 year interval.

Can any maintenance facility perform this work or does it need to be an approved facility.

This is for a Part 91 only plane.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to aviation.stackexchange. I've added the FAA-regulation tag, as I assume you look for answers from the viewpoint of US legislation (you mentione Part 91). If you are looking for answer from the viewpoint of different legislations, please modify the tags accordingly

Comment: Exactly what document states 10 years? And what exactly does it say?  Recommended? Required? Mandatory? Generally in the US, the only aircraft-specific thing that's mandatory, especially for private a/c, is something specified in an AD, or on complex aircraft that have some kind of approved maintenance program.

Comment: When "the manufacturer requires {something}", they typically spell out the details like you're asking about. Go back to the source document that gives the requirement and see what it says. It may say "must be overhauled by the manufacturer" or "at any FAA-approved facility" or something else, and either way, you have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Overhauls are maintenance, and hence anyone can do them, **as long as they have the right certificate (mechanic or repairman), or work under the supervision of one**. The catch is who signs off on the major maintenance for return to service. For that you need someone with FAA inspection authorization, and no IA in his or her right mind will sign off on landing gear maintenance performed by a person or shop with no experience and no certificates or record of supervision.